# How to automatically destroy 1-M connections in MongoDB and Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, database

I am currently building a contest app in which there is a contests collection, questions collection, entries collection, and answers collection. My problem is that I don't know what the best way is to delete all of the questions, answers, and entries that belong to a contest when I delete the contest. This is how I am currently handling the issue:

```
Template.ContestItem.events({
'click .delete': function(e, tmpl) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var currentContestId = this._id;

    var entries = Entries.find({contest_id: currentContestId});

    var questions = Questions.find({contest_id: currentContestId});

    var answers = Answers.find({contest_id: currentContestId});

    answers.forEach(function(answer) {
        Answers.remove(answer._id);
    });

    questions.forEach(function(question) {
        Questions.remove(question._id);
    });

    entries.forEach(function(entry) {
        Entries.remove(entry._id);
    });


    Contests.remove(currentContestId);
  }
});
```

I feel like there has to be a better way to do this though... My solution seems hacked together. I'm not super familiar with MongoDB so this may be an obvious mistake. Please let me know if there is a better way. Thanks!

Here is my repo: https://github.com/ryanswapp/rymotion

Comment: Why not just drop the collection?

Comment: Pretty simple. If you just drop the collection(s) then you do not have the overhead of deleting everything. `.remove()` has a cost. `.drop()` is pretty instant.

Comment: So can I drop a specific document in a collection? I don't want to drop an entire collection because there are still other contests with questions, entries, and answers. I am totally new to nosql so when I hear "drop" I think of completely wiping a relational database.

Comment: Sorry. Great big misread. You want something like "cascading deletes" don't you? I believe there is a mongoose plugin for that. But of course it is not "transactional" since that is not possible across MongoDB collections unless the code base makes all the considerations on the client.

Comment: No worries. Ya, I am looking for something like "dependent: :destroy" on a has_many relation in a Rails model. Maybe MongoDB doesn't have something like that?

Comment: Not sure if anyone has done this for Meteor or "Meteor-Models" but search for the mongoose plugin I mentioned. That should at least give code pointers to how to implement. Good luck, unless someone has a direct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the collection-hooks package and remove all of those items on the after.remove hook:

https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks#afterremoveuserid-doc

```
Template.ContestItem.events({ 'click .delete': function(e, tmpl) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Contests.remove(this._id);
});
```

In some server code:

```
Contests.after.remove(function (userId, contest) {
   Entries.remove({ contest_id: contest._id });
   Questions.remove({ contest_id: contest._id });
   Answers.remove({ contest_id: contest._id });
});
```

Comment: That package looks pretty nice. I think that is what I am looking for. I'll have to give that a shot!

Comment: Glad you found that helpful. It's a must-have package in most Meteor apps.

Answer (score 2):

If you use it in a server method then you can shorten your code:

```
Template.ContestItem.events({
    'click .delete': function(e, tmpl) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var currentContestId = this._id;

        Meteor.call("deleteContest",currentContestId);
    }
});
```

On server:

```
Meteor.methods({
  deleteContest: function(currentContestId) {
    var entries = Entries.remove({contest_id: currentContestId});

    var questions = Questions.remove({contest_id: currentContestId});

    var answers = Answers.remove({contest_id: currentContestId});

    Contests.remove(currentContestId);
    }
});
```

It won't work on the client though, but you don't want to let client remove stuff from db in my opinion. Also being on the server is not async so you can safely let them chain.
Other than that i don't see how you can improve (except validating data like existing contestId and rights to delete or error handling etc.).